# how to change the graph title color

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm working with core plot . When I tried to change the graph title color I found that it's readonly ! 
I had some tries, but now I better ask stackoverflow.

```
        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleTextStyle.color = COLORBALKEN;
barLineChart.titleTextStyle = titleTextStyle;


#define COLORBALKEN [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:211.0/255 green:104.0/255 blue:240.0/255 alpha:1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the appearance of the title of a Core Plot pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763664/change-the-appearance-of-the-title-of-a-core-plot-pie-chart)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code I posted.

I had some mistakes later in code an changed the color back to the collar i din't want . shame on me.

may be some look for changing title color . This code works !